# Solve integrals $\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-v}e^{-e^{-\beta v}}v~\mathrm{d}v$ and $\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-v}e^{-e^{-\beta v}}~\mathrm{d}v$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can the solution to the integrals

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-v}e^{-e^{-\beta v}}v~\mathrm{d}v$$

and

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-v}e^{-e^{-\beta v}}~\mathrm{d}v$$

be computed analytically - or approximated? I have only figured out the trivial solution for $\beta=1$ where I can compute the second integral by

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-v}e^{-e^{-v}}~\mathrm{d}v = \left[e^{-e^{-v}}\right]_{\alpha}^{\infty} = 1 - e^{-e^{-a}}.$$

Comment: Ahmed, check your substitution rule: $t = e^{-v}}$ implies $\textrm{d}t = -e^{-v}}\textrm{d}v$, that is, $-t^-1 \textrm{d}t = \textrm{d}v$. Thus, $I = \int e^{-v}e^{-e^{-v}}~\mathrm{d}v = \int - e^{-t}~\mathrm{d}t = e^{-t}=e^{-e^{-v}}$$

Comment: Yes, then it comes to: $t=e^{-v}$ then $I=\int e^{-v} e^{e^{-bv}} dv=\int e^{t^b} dt$

Answer (score 2):

With $s:=e^{-\beta v}$

$$\int e^{-v}e^{-e^{-\beta v}}dv=-\frac1\beta\int s^{1/\beta-1}e^{-s}ds$$

is an incomplete Gamma integral.

The other integral is more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

For $\beta=1$,
$$I=\int v \,e^{-v}e^{-e^{- v}}dv$$
Let $v=-\log(t)$
$$I=\int e^{-t} \log (t)\,dt$$ One integration by parts
$$I=\text{Ei}(-t)-e^{-t} \log (t)$$ where appears the exponential integral function. So,
$$J=\int_\alpha^\infty v \,e^{-v}e^{-e^{- v}}dv=\gamma-\alpha e^{-e^{-\alpha }}  -\text{Ei}\left(-e^{-\alpha }\right)$$ which is an interesting function.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_\alpha^\infty e^{-v}e^{-e^{-\beta v}}dv$$
$$x=e^{-v}\Rightarrow dv=-e^vdx$$
$$I=-\int_{e^{-\alpha}}^0e^{-x^\beta}dx=\int_0^{e^{-\alpha}}e^{-x^\beta}dx$$
then you could use the series expansion of $e^z$ and interchange the summation and integral